# Row layout for a listView with image view and text view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-listview

I'm using a listView with a custom row layout to show an image and some text on a single line. At the moment I fix the height of the image and the text and I'm using a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rowimage"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/foo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowlabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rowimage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowimage"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

In some devices using 25sp can happen that I've got a two line text and it could be ok for me but the text is not readable because the 55dp for the height is not enough and it's fixed. So I think there are different solutions:

1. Use a dynamic height for the image for auto resize depending on the height of the textView. In this way the height for the row is ok for the text and for the image, but how can I do it?
2. use different layout for different layout screen size, using a different text size
3. Use a smart approach to set a dynamic size of the textview to avoid multi line

I'd like to use the first one, any tips?

Comment: Using dynamic height for the `ImageView` will lead you to the improper UI. Set the Height of the `imageview`, Use `android:singleLine="true"` in your `TextView` and scroll horizontally using marquee.

Comment: Why dont you just use wrap_content for your imageView and textView?

Comment: @Pillai: it could be a solution but I'd prefer to show the text without horizontal scroll if possible.

Comment: @Manishika: if I use wrap_content for both, I see padding above and below the image, ideally I should rescale the image.

Comment: After some tries I found a good balance: layout_height for the relative layout set to wrap_content, the textView layout_height set to wrap_content and for the textView, layout_centerVertical set to true.